# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT with locking clause command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'hibernate_sequence'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I uplifted my hibernate version from 3.x to 5.x

we use spring orm for transaction

found the issue to be located around the below persist method

I find lot of similar issues online but had trouble relating it to hibernate_sequence

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
    public void save(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
```

below is the error log

```
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Mon Sep 12 03:17:51 IST 2022
Sep 22, 2022 4:46:49 AM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1 execute
ERROR: could not read a hi value
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT with locking clause command denied to user 'd7a_viewer'@'localhost' for table 'hibernate_sequence'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.persist(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Aparently your user lacks the permissions. Probably due to a change in hibernate it now does an explicit lock for the serializable transaction.

Comment: we have only ```@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)``` isolation is not specified explicitly. I was trying options

Comment: It has nothing to do with `@Transactional`. You have to check in your database that the user has the correct permissions for the table

Comment: correct me this table 'hibernate_sequence' is managed by hibernate. Not something that i could query over in mysql and provide the grant

Comment: It is a table you can access and provide a grant on. [Read up on sequences](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers#3-sequence-generation).

Comment: It was in your initial post, so you modified it!. Nonetheless it is a security issue with your user which doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer  on the pointer towards the sequences. I missed to highlight the full log ```SEVERE: [The component {0} encountered an error during execution]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804784/spring-replication-issue-with-read-only-user-command-denied  seems to have a pointer to my issue

Comment: i changed my  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) to  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) seems to have deflected the error.

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/487173/databases/hibernate-sequence-exist reference